# Dynamically showing/hiding dynamically-generated <div>s

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I am using PHP to dynamically generate a number of `<select>` fields with two `<div>`s underneath each. An option is automatically selected and the `<div>`s are automatically shown/hidden by PHP based on the initial condition, but how can I dynamically switch which `<div>` is shown/hidden based on a `<select>` change, in addition to making a form field in that `div` either disabled or enabled?

For some background, I am displaying all of the information on the page that could be used, but the `div`s hide each option (using `display:none`) that isn't being used, and each unused `div` also has a disabled form field. When a user selects the other option in the select box, the currently shown `div` needs to be hidden, the `select` inside the `div` needs to be disabled, and the new `div` needs to be shown and its `select` needs to be enabled. I'm doing this because each of the hidden/shown form fields has the same name as I'm posting them to a PHP script.

All of the `<div>`s are in the format of `<div id="textdiv-uniqueID">` OR `<div id="seldiv-uniqueID">`(where `uniqueID` is a unique number for each set of `div`s), and each `select` is in the format of `<select name="uniqueID-good_value">`, where the uniqueID is the same as the corresponding `div`s.

**To recap:** I have a dynamically-generated set of select boxes and form fields. Each select box has two associated form fields, each in its own `<div>`, one of which will be hidden/disabled and the other which will be shown/enabled. When the other option in a given select box is selected, the divs and form fields need to switch roles: the currently hidden/disabled one needs to be shown/enabled, and vice versa.

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sGVHs/) with the basics, including my beginning attempt at figuring out the Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Can you paste the html?  Even a subset would be nice so we could see the structure.  Your explanation is hard to follow.

Comment: Good point, I've added a simple jsFiddle to the original post.

Comment: I still have no idea what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

In general, something similar to what you need looks like this:

```
$('#uniqueID-good_value').on('change',function (){
    var val= $(this).val();
    if(val==1) {
        $('textdiv-uniqueID').show();
        $('seldiv-uniqueID').hide();
    }else{
        $('textdiv-uniqueID').hide();
        $('seldiv-uniqueID').show();
    }
});
```

for your case, you need to work a bit on the logic to make it work smart with the uniqueid.

Comment: It is better practise to use on like `$('parentThatContainsAllYourDynamicContent').on('event', 'selectorForDynamicContent', function(){ //do something });` because on binds the event to the element, if you bind it to the parent, it will only be bound once, and include any newly added elements within the bind. If you do it like you're doing now, you're generating extra resource usage by binding the event on each and every element that matches the selector. While it won't work for extra added content.

Comment: I've started using something like this (I'm brand new to Javascript/jQuery and I'm still trying to learn the ropes), but I can't get it to work. [Here's an oversimplified jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sGVHs/) Any chance you'd be able to point out what's wrong?

Comment: You can use a tool like firebug to see the error messages. What is wrong is that  `var arr = $(this).name.split("-");` cannot work, because a jQuery object may refer to several objects with distinct names. You can use plain Javascript however: `var arr = this.name.split("-");` I tried to test this in jsFiddle, but how do you update it after editing it?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just put a class of 'active' or 'hidden' on the relevant fields, and then swap the class when things change?

For instance:

$(".active").removeClass("active").addClass("hidden");

You could put that into an event on your select widgets (I'm not sure what all the available events are, but there must be something like onselect or onselected, and there's always onmouseup)